# Checking pending (not yet in the blockchain) transactions

Tags: transactions, blockchain, confirmations

Is there a service (like Blockexplorer) that shows pending transactions that have not (yet?) been included in the block chain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even transactions with no confirmations will show in the results (unless the transaction has been sitting unconfirmed for some time and then the service stops tracking it):

- http://www.BlockChain.info

Comment: I couldn't find a way to search for unconfirmed transactions on BlockChain and the 2nd link is broken.

Comment: Any search for a bitcoin address on Blockchain.info will yield any transaction it has seen regardless of the confirmations.  The only exception is if the transaction didn't confirm and the service no longer tracks it ... which happens after about a day when no confirmation ever occurs.